# If enough particles collide into one another won't they eventually stop moving?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

If enough particles collide into one another won't they eventually move less than the Planck length over the lifetime of the universe? Does this violate conservation of momentum?

Answer (score 1):

Dear idkwhttomakemynamestoppressuri,

If the particles were moving originally, then due to conservation of energy some would still be moving even after a long time idkwhtmoretosay.

Answer (score -1):

Momentum will be conserved here too.

You're talking about inelastic collisions so kinetic energy is lost here, and the bodies move with a common velocity u after the collision.

Let all the masses have their own individual velocities before collision, and assume the conservation of momentum to hold here too, then we get the following:

$$m_1v_1+m_2v_2+m_3v_3+... = (m_1+m_2+m_3+...)u$$

To provide a very intuitive answer, you can see that if "enough" particles collide then the mass of the final body is so large (sum of all the participating masses) that the velocity must be very less to conserve momentum, so less that it may appear almost stationary.

Hence your situation does not violate COM, in fact it is a result of it!